# PowerShell & Power BI Rest API

Tags: powershell, csv, powerbi, rest

Essentially what I'm after is the results of rest API Gateways - Get Datasource Users but retaining the ID (in this example $Line.id from my imported CSV file).

The end result should be a CSV with the following fields -
ID, emailAddress, datasourceAccessRight, displayName, identifier, principalType

I'm new to PowerShell and surprised I got this far but can't figure out this final bit.

Cheers

```
$webclient=New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$webclient.Proxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials

$Dir = "C:\pbi_pro_user_logs\"

Login-PowerBI

$GateWayFile = Import-CSV -Path "C:\pbi_pro_user_logs\Gateway_Detail.csv"
$Output = @()
foreach ($Line in $GateWayFile){
    $Item = $Line.id
    $url =  "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/gateways/HIDDEN/datasources/"+$Item+"/users"
    $Output += (Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url $url -Method Get | ConvertFrom-Json)
}

$Result = $Output.value

$Result | Export-Csv $Dir"GateWay_users.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: What exactly is not working for you? It looks like you're getting some data and saving it to a CSV already, are you just missing some fields?

Comment: So, the above works but only brings back the results of 'Gateways - Get Datasource Users ' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/gateways/get-datasource-users. I would like it to retain the datasource ID used if that makes sense?  When you use this API you enter the datasource ID to get a list of users for that datasource but the ID is not a field in the result.  I would like to see the ID in the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, using a calculated property from `Select-Object`:

```
$GateWayFile = Import-CSV -Path "C:\pbi_pro_user_logs\Gateway_Detail.csv"
$Output = Foreach ($Line in $GateWayFile){
    $url =  "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/gateways/HIDDEN/datasources/"+$Line.id+"/users"
    $Item = (Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url $url -Method Get | ConvertFrom-Json)

    # output all properties of the item, plus the ID:
    $ItemWithID = $Item | Select *,@{l='Id';e={$line.id}}
    Write-Output $ItemWithID
}

# This depends on how you want your csv structured, but for example:
$Result = $Output | Select Id,Value
```

Or, if `Value` is a whole object that `ID` should be assigned inside of, then change the selection lines:

```
  $ItemWithID = $Item.Value | Select *,@{l='Id';e={$line.id}}
$Result = $Output
```